# "getting worse and worse " vs " got worse and worse"

Tags: continuous

"I remember xxxxx   at that time getting more and more depressed, he got worse and worse "

I don't undrestand why it is not he **was getting** worse and worse (because getting depressed and the immediate consequence getting  worse and worse take a long time  . Both are "process"
Is it because worse and worse implies a continuous thing so it is no use choosing a continuous tense

Comment: ok so why not he got more and more depressed because if he stopped getting worse he also stop getting depressed so both have an end

Comment: I deleted my comment because I don't think it was really correct.  I'm a native speaker but of course analysing language is not identical to understanding it, I get it wrong sometimes, that's part of why I enjoy answering :-)  Let's hope somebody comes along who'll do a better job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writer could have used the continuous form.

The use of non-default aspecual forms in English (continuous forms, perfect forms) is nearly always optional, depending not on external circumstances, but on how the speaker is *choosing* to present the temporal relationships and contours.

In this case, the speaker had already used a continuous aspect in the first clause, choosing to present it as a continuing process. As I say, they could have done so in the second half, but it was not necessary, because that presentation was already there.

Comment: I think on purely stylistic grounds it's far better *not* to keep unnecessarily repeating the more complex continuous verb form in the specific cited example. In many other contexts, *consistency* would be the deciding factor, but not if it comes at the cost of adding [significant] unnecessary complexity.

Comment: does that mean that he got worse and worse in this case have both significations the continuous thing and the completed thing (at one point he stopped getting worse )

Comment: @YvesLefol:Not sure quite what your question is. You can't deduce anything about whether he stopped getting worse or not, The simple past is what linguists call the [unmarked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness), which doesn't necessarily make such distinctions. If you used a simple past on its own, without preceding it with a continuous form, then the fact that the speaker had chosen to present it as a completed fact _might_ suggest that the process had finished; but paired with a continuous form like this, it doesn't even have that implication.